# Pass argument to function as quoted string

Tags: r, function, parsing, arguments

I want to write function which read file from specific location into dataframe like below:

```
check = function(file, loc){
  
  myData = read.delim()
  return(myData)
}

check(/aaa/bbbb/cccc/, xxxx.log)
```

But I don't know how to pass argument to funtion as:

```
myData=read.delim("/aaa/bbbb/cccc/xxxx.log")
```

I will be glad for help.

Comment: I couldn't get what you want. Maybe is `myData = read.delim(paste0(file, log))`. Also you don't need to save the read file into a variable to return it, you can do just `function(...){read.delim(...)}`

Comment: use `myData <- read.delim(file.path(file, log))`

Comment: what if I have argument loc without first '/' like this: check(aaa/bbbb/cccc/, xxxx.log). It won't read file without it. How to add it into file.path? paste0 is not working (paste0("/", loc))

Comment: It's not possible because the / is intercepted by the parser.

Comment: So is there any way to read a file with below arguments? check(aaa/bbbb/cccc/, xxxx.log)

Comment: You can use `as.character(substitute(x))` but you should not because it will fail for some valid files. You should just use quoted strings.